# How to continuously fetch new data AND have ability inject something different at the middle of the process?

Tags: algorithm, architecture

I don't know if there was any question like this, please suggest as I can not find one.

Current I want to implement a feature, in which data is large and I do not want to fetch at once. I can do it like this with Promise.all:

```
start: fetch 100 first rows.
after delay: fetch 101 - 200 rows, wait...
after delay: fetch 201 - 300 rows, wait...
and so on until finish 100k+ rows.
```

But the problem is when user scroll down, let say, to middle of the page, and it's required to load 20k rows, I do not want user wait for loading screen, so I want to do something like this:

```
start: load 100 first rows.
after delay: fetch 101 - 200 rows, wait...
user scrolls to row 20000, fetch data from 20000 - 20100, wait...
after delay: fetch 201 - 300 rows, wait...
and so on until row 20000, skip.
after delay: fetch 20101 - 20200 rows, wait...
and so on until finish.
```

My question is, is there any proper solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to prefetch so many items?

Comment: Do a [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) when the user reaches bottom of the page on scrolling.

Comment: Combining the two other comments: on page load, show 10 first items only and load the rest only on demand. [Pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination#In_web_browsers) could also be an alternative.

Comment: the basic variation is: with a setInterval fetch periodically, upon user request, fetch its proper data. (that is you may have two requests running in parallel). If you want to avoid parallel requests, you may want a handle on your periodical ajax request to abort it (+ a boolean to shut the timer during user interaction). Generally though, the optimization does not come from aborting the requests but from preventing user requests to be fired too many times (debounce)

Comment: @OndrejTucny I'm working on an app, which works somehow similar to Excel or Google Sheet, but heavily customized for customers' needs. Customers want the ability to copy/paste, for example from Excel/Google Sheet with many thousands of rows into our system. Pagination does not work in this case.

Comment: @vivek_23 in my case the lazy loading does not fulfill the requirements.